# Direct proof of measure zero implies empty interior

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

I've been told that any measure zero set $S$ has empty interior.

I proved it this way : if it had non-empty interior then there would exist an non-empty open set $U\subset S$ such that $x \in U \implies \exists B(x,\delta) \subset U$. Then, $m(S)\geq m(B(x,\delta))>0$, contradiction.

However, I wanted to know if there was a direct proof because I couldn't think of one.

Comment: you can't do better... what do you mean by direct proof ? this is a direct proof...

Comment: I meant starting from a measure zero set and showing that it has empty interior

Comment: @Surb, intuitionists don't accept proof by contradiction!

Comment: @Ruy lol nice joke haha. I was just asking about a proof that starts with a measure zero set and shows somehow it has empty interior, no conspiracy behind it

Comment: I didn't mean to insult anyone!  Intuitionists and, also constructivists, are normal people.  They just have different standards of proof!

Comment: any thoughts on the converse?

Comment: @GustavoDeSouza its false, consider $\Bbb R \backslash \Bbb Q $